# Ubuntu: How to mount zfs snapshot?

Tags: mount, zfs

I'm trying to mount zfs snapshot. It should to be so easy...but I can't do that. 
I'm using Ubuntu Server 11.10 Oneric, kernel 3.0.0-15-server.

Installed ZFS from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/daily) also I'm using zfs-auto-snapshot. 
With manually created snapshots the same situations.

**How to mount zfs snapshot?**

```
root@us1:/# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                                                            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/www@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2012-02-11-1917                   0      -   268K  -

root@us1:/# zfs mount tank/www@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2012-02-11-1917 /mnt/snapshot/tank/www
too many arguments
usage:
        mount
        mount [-vO] [-o opts] <-a | filesystem>

For the property list, run: zfs set|get

For the delegated permission list, run: zfs allow|unallow

root@us1:/# zfs mount tank/www@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2012-02-11-1917
cannot open 'tank/www@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2012-02-11-1917': operation not applicable to datasets of this type
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Running ZoL, just use the regular mount command like this:

```
mount -t zfs tank/www@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2012-02-11-1917 /mnt/snapshot/tank/www
```

Dismount it like this:

```
umount /mnt/snapshot/tank/www
```

This is a bug that is being tracked at https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/173

Comment: Great tip to mount ZFS dataset without changing the mountpoint parameter

Answer (score 38):

As of today, ZFS on Linux (ZoL) now also supports read-only access to snapshots via a invisible (not hidden, invisible) directory in the root of the dataset.

```
# ls -a /tank/test
./  ../  boot.tar  text.tar  text.tar.2
# cd /tank/test/.zfs/
# ls -a
./  ../  shares/  snapshot/
```

In the `snapshot` directory you'll find read-only copies of all your snapshots.

You can make `.zfs` visible via `zfs set snapdir=visible tank/test`.

Source: https://pthree.org/2012/12/19/zfs-administration-part-xii-snapshots-and-clones/

Comment: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332192/how-are-files-dirs-hidden-from-ls-a-while-still-being-accessible-otherwise-in-a#comment584984_332192)'s  a reason why it's not visible by default

Comment: once I unmounted one of the snapshot inside .zfs directory, all the snapshots no longer showing in snapshot/ .. to fix it I do zfs set snapdir=hidden  and then zfs set snapdir=visible

Comment: for anyone else stumbling: since it's invisible, shells will (obviously) not autocomplete it...